# Excel Macro : Error 9, If × Countif

Tags: vba, excel

エラーコード'9'の解消方法を教えてください。以下の`If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf`の部分です。

```
Sub Downloaded()

    n = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim i

    For i = 2 To n

        If Range("o" & i) = 0 Then
            Range("a" & i).Value = ""
        Else
            Range("a" & i).Value = Range("o" & i).Value
        End If

        ' 下記のIf文に対してエラーが表示される
        If (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(Unsubscribers), Range("A:A").Value) = 0) Then
            Range("b2").Value = "Subscribed"
        Else
            Range("b2").Value = "Unsubscribed"
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

VBAのエラーコード　９は、”インデックスが有効範囲にありません”("Index Out of Range")というエラーです。

```
WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Worksheets(Unsubscribers), Range("A:A").Value
```

で使われている　Unsubscribers は質問のコードの中で宣言されていないし、値の代入もされていませんから、その値は Empty であると考えられます。

Worksheets("filename") は、ワークシート名がfilenameであるworksheetオブジェクトです。
ワークシート名がEmptyであるworksheetは存在しないので、Worksheets(Empty)は”インデックスが有効範囲にありません”というエラーになります。
＝＝[回答　第一部は、ここまで]＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝

質問者から「シートAのA列目にあるものとシートBのA列にあるものを識別して、シートAのB列に重複の有無をYes/Noで表示したいのです」とのコメントがあったので、エラーの解消方法ではなく、プログラムについての回答をしたいと思います。

＝＝[回答　第二部]＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝＝
＜おことわり＞
質問のコードには、２つのシート（AとB)に対応するオブジェクトが出てきません。
また、A列、B列以外にF列、O列のセルが使われていますが、何がしたかったのか理解できませんでした。

そこで、以下のように単純化したコードの例を示します。
・ActiveSheetが”シートA”で、”シートB”は"Unsubscribers"という名前のシートの事。
・”シートA”のA列のセルの値が、”シートB”のA列のセルに出現しているかどうかを調べて、値の右側（B列)のセルに"Yes"か"No"を書き込む。

```
Sub sampleCode()
    Dim sheetA as worksheet, sheetB as worksheet 'worksheetオブジェクト用の変数
    Dim rowNo as Integer, rowMax as Integer '行を表す変数と、データの最終行を表す変数

    Set sheetA = ActiveSheet
    Set sheetB = worksheets("Unsubscribers")

    rowMax = sheetA.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For rowNo = 2 to rowMax
      if (WorksheetFunction.CountIf(sheetB.Range("A:A"),sheetA.Cells(rowNo,1))>0) Then 'SheetBのA列に、SheetAのA列rowNo行のセルの値が含まれていた
        sheetA.Cells(rowNo,2)="Yes" '右のセルにYesと書き込む
      Else
        sheetA.Cells(rowNo,2)="No"  '右のセルにNoと書き込む
      End If
    next rowNo
End Sub
```

コード中の"sheetA."の部分は無くても動きますが、どちらのシートのセルを扱っているのかを明示するために入れました。

Comment: Workbook内にUnsubscribersという名前のシートがありますが、これを選択出来ていないということでしょうか？

Comment: @Beginner 実際のシート名を指定するなら恐らく `Worksheets("Unsubscribers")` の様に文字列をダブルクォートでくくる必要があります。質問文の様な書き方だと `Unsubscriers` という`変数`が書かれたものとみなされてエラーになります。

Comment: @cubick-san ありがとうございます。シートAのA列目にあるものとシートBのA列にあるものを識別して、シートAのB列に重複の有無をYes/Noで表示したいのですが

Comment: @Beginner 回答する人は質問文に書かれた情報を元に回答するので、解決したい課題があるのならその情報も含めて質問文に書かないと伝わりません(例：○○したいが××のエラーが表示される)。現状だと単に「エラーが出ます」だけなので、見た人はエラーに対してしか回答を付けられません。質問は後からでも「編集」できるので必要に応じて見直してください。